# Testing UI select using Protractor.Net based on index?

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular-ui-select, protractor-net

I am testing the UI select using Protractor.NET. I had referred the following link for testing the UI select -
[Testing with protractor using ui-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055349/testing-with-protractor-using-ui-select)

My problem which I am running into is that the data from the list item varies. So I can't hard code the value.

Is there a way to test the UI select based on an index so that whatever the items, I can send an index value as 0 which would satisfy my requirements.

Edited: Included the code

```
       var getCountry = NgDriver
           .FindElement(NgBy.Model("vm.Country"))
           .FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-select-container"));

        getCountry.Click();

        var selectedCountryItem = getCountry.FindElement(By.ClassName("ui-select-search"));
        selectedCountryItem.SendKeys("Iran");
        selectedCountryItem.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

The above code works perfectly as I have hard coded to **Iran**. I need to send an index instead of this hard coded value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @rajanasekhar - Take a look now